# C - How do I fill an array with certain numbers

Tags: c

For example if u have an array of size [250] and u want to fill it with 10% of being '1' , 30% of it being '2' and the rest just '3'. How do i approach this? I know how to fill an array with random numbers but i'm clueless here.

Comment: The answers you've gotten assumes that you want the numbers to be placed randomly - but that's not what you're asking. If that's indeed that you want to know, please state that in the question - otherwise, the comment below contains the bulk of a valid answer to your question.

Comment: Any specific ordering requirement? `int i = 0; while (i < 25) arr[i++] = 1; while (i < 100) arr[i++] = 2; while (i < 250) arr[i++] = 3;` does the job you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest, if not necessarily fastest - set the first 25 elements to `1`, the next 75 elements to `2`, and the remaining elements to `3`, then do a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to randomly reorder them.

Answer (score 0):

Write 25x `'1'`, 75x `'2'` and the rest `'3'` using plain for loops, nothing random. Then make an algorithm that shuffles the array by repeatedly swapping two items at random indices and repeat it a certain number of times.